# How to use libflutter_linux_glfw.so file and related files from out/host_debug of flutter engine

Tags: flutter

I followed instructions from [Setting up the Engine development](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Setting-up-the-Engine-development-environment) to build the flutter engine. Purpose of this was to use the texture support from [Texture support for glfw](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/9822). I could compile the flutter engine.

Next I wanted to use this engine and develop Texture based application. While compiling using the following command, I see that libflutter_linux_glfw.so and other platform files are copied from flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine.

```
flutter build linux
```

I added the dependency_overrides to pubspec.yaml as follows. But, no luck.

```
dependency_overrides:   
  sky_engine:   
    path: <base folder of engine>/engine/src/out/host_debug_unopt/gen/dart-pkg/sky_engine   
  sky_services: 
    path: <base folder of engine>/engine/src/out/host_debug_unopt/gen/dart-pkg/sky_services
```

Looking forward for the suggestions on the changes required to use files from engine/src/out/host_debug_unopt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could use compiled libflutter_linux_glfw.so by using --local-engine-src-path and --local-engine options of flutter given in the following link.

[Using a locally-built engine with the flutter tool](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/The-flutter-tool)